# Sort ArrayList in descending order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

So I'm trying to sort my ArrayList from greatest to least.  The user can only enter in numbers, which is then turned into a String.  And that is all working very well, but when I display my scores I get something like this...

```
98
81
81
76
64
105
103
100
```

Anyone know how to make it sort...

```
105
103
100
98
81
81
76
64
```

Comment: What's wrong with an ArrayList <int>?

Comment: @Steven We're all done with our homework for the year, and the professor is just giving out extra assignments to anyone who wants to try them.  I had it sorting in descending order, but it would list it from greatest two-digits to three-digits.  If that makes any sense lol

Comment: So, what have you tried? With what part of the assigment are you stuck? And which technology are you targeting? .NET? Java? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are keeping the numbers as `String`s and hence you are sorting them lexicographically (`'9'` comes after `'1'`). Instead, you should parse the strings to `Integer`s (e.g., using `Integer.valueOf`) and stored in an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Now, when you sort it, the elements will be evaluated according to their numerical value.

Comment: that worked perfectly!  I'm using the NetBeans JOptionPane, and when I have the program take in the number I just have the Integer.parseInt(textfield), instead of just adding the String.

Answer (score 2):

Dom - Keep in mind that a string is a bunch of chars, and each char has a integer value.  Sorting strings !== sorting numbers.

Comment: Thank you that also helped me solve my problem.  I've been programming Bukkit Minecraft plugins and doing this Java programming school work and they're kinda conflicting with the way Java works in my brain haha

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code

```
    List<String> firstArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    firstArrayList.add("4"); // .add(readUSerInput());
    firstArrayList.add("30");
    firstArrayList.add("1");
    firstArrayList.add("02");

    ArrayList<Integer> newArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(String numero: firstArrayList){
        newArrayList.add(Integer.parseInt(numero));
    }

    newArrayList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());

    // To check
    for(Integer numero: newArrayList){
        // use a Scanner() to print numero to the screen
    }
```

Comment: What is Util.afficher()?

Comment: Won't that sort it in ASCENDING order?

Comment: thank you for noticing, i edited accordingly, use Collection.reverseOrder()

Comment: Hello Justin. Well... Actually it does work, i tried this code on eclipse and got the correct ordre with correct Integer class. I'll delete if needed but i dont understand why you think it does not work.

Comment: My bad, I missed the copy of the array list!.  In your example you only have single digit strings, which can give the right answer for the wrong solution.  Sorry about that.